# How can I inspect and audit the non-xml portion of a configuration profile?

Tags: security, mdm, configuration-profiles, xml

There is a very useful configuration profile published by my ISP.

But: I am careful about such things and want to inspect it.

The XML portion of the configuration profile is very straightforward.

BUT! After the XML portion is the encoded garbage text that I do not have the abilities to make sense of.

It **looks** like the non-XML portion of a configuration profile is just a certificate chain and ... maybe a checksum ?

What is contained in the non-XML portion of a configuration profile and how can I view it in a way to reassure myself that nothing bad is hidden in the parts I cannot read ?

`strings` is the only tool I know how to pull info out of that portion but it doesn't give me very much at all.  How to decode it ?

Comment: I would still like to know the answer to my question but in my case, I simply opened the configuration profile in 'vi' and removed all of the binary data, stripped away the ^M characters, resaved it and then imported it without any problem. So there is no need to audit the non-xml portion if you can just rip it out ... but it would still be nice to be able to view and inspect the binary data ...